# How to retrieve a data property value from just knowing the individual and class name in Protégé, by SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I started using Protégé as required by my job and currently learning how to use SPARQL Query for it.

I got a question in my mind as following:

Let's say that I have an ontology as this:
`-owl:thing > -Phone`
, so the "Phone" is a subclass of the class "owl:thing".
The class "Phone" has the following individuals "Galaxy" and "iPhone".
Each individual is classified through a Data Property "hasVersion".
The individual "iPhone" has got a version value "X-MAX" through that Data Property "hasVersion".
So the relation is as following:

```
{ iPhone hasVersion X-MAX }
```

The individual "Galaxy" has got a version value "S10" through that Data Property "hasVersion".
So the relation is as following:

```
{ Galaxy hasVersion S10 }
```

So the question now is that what is the right SPARQL query to retrieve the version value of the individual "iPhone " which is "X-MAX" without explicitly mentioning the "X-MAX" value?

So simply that I know the individual name and the data property, but don't know the value of the "hasVersion" data property, so want to retrieve the data property value that belong to the "iPhone" individual.

In other words, I know the class name "Phone" + the individal name "iPhone", but dont know the version value of "iPhone". Also, I just want the version value that belong to the indinvdual "iPhone", not want to see of "Galaxy".

I have tried something like this, but didn't work:

```
:iPhone :hasVersion ?VersionValue .
```

Comment: 1) it would be good to show the whole query 2) `SELECT * WHERE {:iPhone :hasVersion ?VersionValue .}` should indeed work as long as you defined the prefix `:` to be the correct one from your data - and yes, `:` is a prefix and has to be declared. So, did you check your prefix declaration already?

Comment: also, is `:iPhone` the correct URI? OR do you just have it attached to some other property, e.g. `rdfs:label`, `:name` or whatever and it is a string literal?

Comment: You are right. The only thing that I missed is adding the same URI but with an end of "#" instead "/". I think this is due to that the individuals have "#" at their URI end while classes/properties have "/". Thanks btw.